# Blend Smooth tool leaves random empty holes

Tags: smooth

Currently I have a model and I go to Blend Smooth, but after clicking the option I am left with parts of the model that are left empty and distorted. I tried adding more lines and tried refilling parts where the holes appeared, but I still cant completely smooth the model. This is my first time using Blender and I am just learning to use the software. [image]             [image: As you can see after clicking the blend smooth option the model is left with holes and distortions]

Comment: This may be topology related (tri's and n-gon's), but one thing to try before messing with that is to make sure all the surface normals are pointed the right way (Select all in edit mode then Shift+N)

Comment: If Christopher's solutions don't work, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I tried your fix with making sure the surface normals were correct and it didnt seem to work. I am sharing my file.